# Commuting cohomologies for bounded double complex

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

For a bounded double complex $D$ with differentials $d_1,d_2$ we know that $H(H(D,d_1),d_2)=H(H(D,d_2),d_1)$.

Does anyone know of a reference for the proof without using spectral sequences?

Thanks!

EDIT: I should add both spectral sequences degenerate on page 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn’t true. For example, take the double complex with the only two nonzero rows
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\cdots@>>>0@>>>0@>>>\mathbb{Z}@>>>\mathbb{Z}@>>>0@>>>\cdots\\
@.@VVV@VVV@VVV@VVV@VVV\\
\cdots@>>>0@>>>\mathbb{Z}@>>>\mathbb{Z}@>>>0@>>>0@>>>\cdots
\end{CD}$$
where the maps between copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ are all isomorphisms.

Comment: Thanks, what about if both spectral sequences degenerate on page 2? Is there an elementary proof for the commuting cohomologies?

Comment: @Steve If by “elementary” you mean “without spectral sequences”, how would you express the fact that both spectral sequences degenerate?

Comment: Sorry maybe I should've been more specific: the double complex that I got $D_{m,n}$ is exact except at 1 degree for both differentials $d_1,d_2$. That is $d_1$ is exact except at $D_{0,n}$ for all $n$ and $d_2$ is exact at $D_{m,0}$ for all $m$. I am trying to find an elementary proof for $H(H(D,d_1),d_2)=H(H(D,d_2),d_1)$ (which I think is true?).

Comment: @Steve In that specific case I think you can show, using (several times) the homology long exact sequence of a short exact sequence of complexes, applied to short exact sequences coming from cunningly chosen truncations, that the homology of the total complex is isomorphic to $H(H(D,d_1),D_2)$. And then of course the same proof shows that it's also isomorphic to $H(H(D,d_2),d_1)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I ask what 'short exact sequence of complexes' is in this case? And what did you mean by 'truncations'? Thanks!

Comment: @Steve Try https://stacks.math.columbia.edu Sections 12.12 and 12.14. Though I was thinking of versions of 12.14 for double complexes, truncating at a given row or column.